# std::atomic with externally provided address

Tags: c++, c++11

Can `std::atomic` be used without constructing it?

For example we might want to use it across processes with memory mapped files. It does not seem possible to use a `std::atomic` in some location without destroying the value of that location. Constructing a `std::atomic` in-place would destroy the previous value (I think).

Comment: Did you try to use reference to atomic?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot how would that work? I don't think it's defined behavior to treat an arbitrary location as a certain class.

Comment: If there is atomic (constructed by another process) already, you can link reference to it. If there is no atomic, you will have to construct it anyway (by some of shared processed)

Comment: Could be a memory mapped file filled with anything provided by a 3rd party.